# Find the volume of rotation about the y-axis for the region bounded by $y=5x-x^2$, and $x^2-5x+8$

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, spheres

Find the volume of rotation about the y-axis for the region bounded by $y=5x-x^2$, and $x^2-5x+8$

Here is an image:

[image]

Normally I can do this question, but this one is tricky because since we are rotating about the y-axis, and we are quadratic, when I solve for $x$ I get two answers, one positive and one negative.

What I mean is that if you look at the graph $5x-x^2$, then there are two halves, and if you look at the green line, that's one half of the curve (positive one), and the red half is the negative one.

Since we can see both the negative and positive sections in this graph, and **both** are being rotated, I wasn't sure how to create the equation that I can later integrate.

Usually in the problems I do, the negative doesn't exist, and so it's trivial. In this case I am not sure.

Comment: You can use symmetry if you wish. But, more important, are you using cross-sections or cylindrical shells?

Comment: Any standard Calculus textbook would have two methods in it for finding volumes of solids of revolution: the disks/washers method and the shells method. What you're thinking about here is the former, and indeed it's going to be terribly difficult. Instead you should use the latter.

Comment: @zipirovich If I use shell, what would the radius of shell be? Would it be $x$

Comment: Yes, here it is $x$.

Comment: @zipirovich but why? We do not touch the y-axis and so theres still a section thats rotated, but not directly touching the y-axis

Comment: You're thinking about disks/washers again. You should read about the cylindrical shells method somewhere. Think about an empty thin tin can as an example of a cylindrical shell. The volume of a single shell is the volume of such a tin can -- meaning how much tin was used to make it, not what it contains. Its dimensions are its thickness, which is a very small number because it's thin ($dx$ is this question), its height, and then there's its radius -- which means the distance from the axis to the circumference of the can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area between two functions is 
$$\pi\int_{y_1}^{y_2}f^2(y)-g^2(y)dy$$
where $x=f(y)$ is right curve and $x=g(y)$ is left curve.

You have two curves which certain area from $[\dfrac{7}{4},\dfrac{25}{4}]$ and intersect in $y=4$. Without using symmetry, this interval is union of $[\dfrac{7}{4},4]$ and $[4,\dfrac{25}{4}]$. With your graph you can obtain the area
\begin{align}
{\bf V}
&=\pi\int_\frac{7}{4}^4\left(\dfrac{5+\sqrt{4y-7}}{2}\right)^2-\left(\dfrac{5-\sqrt{4y-7}}{2}\right)^2dy \\
&+\pi\int_4^\frac{25}{4}\left(\dfrac{5+\sqrt{-4y+25}}{2}\right)^2-\left(\dfrac{5-\sqrt{-4y+25}}{2}\right)^2dy \\
&=\color{blue}{45\pi}
\end{align}
details left to you.

Comment: What method did you use here? Shell or Disc/Washer?

Comment: Disc/Washer it is!

Comment: Oh yikes that seems like the hard approach Dx

Comment: @KSplitX Without using symmetry yes, but you can make it simpler.

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to match the one below

Comment: I'm actually not sure what the answer is in this case, but I believe Math's because the shell method makes more sense in this case, not to say yours is wrong, but i cannot be certain of any

Comment: I have another idea. use parametric version of this!

Answer (score 2):

As your graph shows, there are no "negative" sections being rotated.  The two graphs intersect at $x=1$ and $x=4$. Between these two x-values, the lower curve is $y_1=x^2-5x+8$ and the upper curve is $y_2=5x-x^2$.

Think about a small vertical strip of width $dx$ and length $y_2 - y_1$ being rotated about the y-axis.  The infinitesimal volume of this rotated strip is $2\pi(y_2-y_1)dx$.  You just need to integrate this from $x=1$ to $x=4$.  *i.e.*,
$$V = \int_1^4 2\pi x (y_2-y_1)dx = 2\pi\int_1^4(10x^2-2x^3-8x)dx = 45 \pi$$.

Comment: Im not so sure the shell radius would be $x$, simply because we do not ever "touch" the y-axis

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some confusion here that can be clarified with a simpler approach, namely Pappus's ($2^{nd}$) Centroid Theorem: the volume of a planar area of revolution is the product of the area $A$ and the length of the path traced by its centroid $R$, i.e., $2πR$. The bottom line is that the volume is given simply by $V=2\pi RA$.

In the present problem, the area is given by

$$
y_1=5x-x^2\\
y2=x^2-5x+8\\
A=\int_1^4(y_1-y_2)~dx=9\\
$$

The centroid is readily obtained because of the symmetry, to wit,

$$\mathbf{R}=(R_x,R_y)=(2.5,4)$$

And therefore, the volume of rotation about the $y$-axis is

$$V_y=2\pi R_xA=2\pi\cdot 2.5\cdot 9=45\pi$$

Similarly, the rotation about the $x$-axis is

$$V_y=2\pi R_yA=2\pi\cdot 4\cdot 9=72\pi$$

I have verified these results numerically.

Answer (score 0):

Here I use parametric method for finding volume and also use symmetry to make the problem simpler. As the upper and lower graph about $y=4$ 
are the same, so we restrict ourselves to interval $[\dfrac{7}{4},4]$. For $y=5x−x^2$ we see
$$y=5x−x^2=\dfrac{25}{4}-\left(x-\dfrac52\right)^2=\dfrac{25}{4}-t^2$$
so paramertic form of this curve is
\begin{cases}
x=t+\dfrac52,\\
y=\dfrac{25}{4}-t^2.
\end{cases}
where $-\dfrac32\leqslant t\leqslant0$ for left curve and $0\leqslant t\leqslant\dfrac32$ for right curve, thus
$${\bf V}=\int_a^b\pi x^2\dfrac{dy}{dt}dt=2 \left(\pi  \int_{-\frac{3}{2}}^0 \left(t+\frac{5}{2}\right)^22 t \, dt+\pi  \int_0^{\frac{3}{2}} \left(t+\frac{5}{2}\right)^2 2 t \, dt \right)=\color{blue}{45\pi}$$